# How is the Resource class correctly overwritten to implement a dynamic translation system?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-resources, layout-inflater

Hello to all Android Developers, I need to clarify a doubt in relation to the management of dynamic resources in Android applications.

I need my application to use the translations returned by my backend depending on the language configured on the phone.

I wanted to implement it in an elegant way working on a custom **LayoutInflater** that applies a **ViewTransformer** depending on the type of graphic component.

Each ViewTransformer will only collect the identifier (for example @id/landing_welcome_text) and make the next call:

```
 val value = attrs.getAttributeValue(index)
 if (value != null && value.startsWith("@")) {
      val text = view.context.resources.getString(attrs.getAttributeResourceValue(index, 0))
     setTextForView(view, text)
 }
```

A ContextWrapper has been implemented that returns my custom LayoutInflater and a Resource implementation

```
override fun getSystemService(name: String): Any {
   return if (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE == name)
      CustomLayoutInflater(
          LayoutInflater.from(baseContext),
                this,
                viewTransformerManager
            )
      else
            super.getSystemService(name)
}

override fun getResources(): Resources = customResources
```

**The problem is that overwriting the behavior of the Resources class is considered a deprecated strategy.**

As the documentation says:

> This constructor is deprecated. Resources should not be constructed by
>   apps. See Context.createConfigurationContext(Configuration).

```
class CustomResourcesWrapper constructor(
    res: Resources,
    private val languageStringRepo: ILanguageStringRepo
): Resources(res.assets, res.displayMetrics, res.configuration) {


    @Throws(Resources.NotFoundException::class)
    override fun getString(id: Int): String {
        val value = getStringFromRepository(id)
        return value ?: super.getString(id)
    }

}
```

Does anyone know how I can get the same functionality without overwriting the Resources class?

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Why not have your `ViewModel` supply the proper strings to your activity/fragment, which just fills them in the way you would any other dynamic data? Given that a server is involved, you are going to need to take network+disk I/O and threading into account anyway, no different than you do for any other operations with your server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this strategy seems to me more automatic and is encapsulated in the process of inflating the views, I would not like to see logic of translations in all the viewModels of my features. I have the translations loaded in an in-memory LRU cache, access is immediate.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this with ViewModel, the screen could appear without text until I load the translations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was looking into the same thing some time ago, in the end our team decided to go with [Lokalise SDK](https://docs.lokalise.co/en/articles/1400668-lokalise-android-sdk).

From what I found out, overriding resources is the only way to do it. And even then it still doesn't cover all the cases, like mentioned in Lokalise documentation:

> Some views are not supported when inflating from XML (Action bar, Menu
>   items, Android preferences, may be others), but you can still get the
>   latest translations via getString(), getText(), getQuantityString()
>   and other system methods, and set the content of these views
>   programmatically.

I saw a similar implementation in this library https://github.com/hamidness/restring although it wasn't nearly as complete as Lokalise. You can see how Lokalise is implemented if you include their library and switch to `Project` view in Android Studio, expand `External Libraries` and find `com.lokalise.android`, then you can see the decompiled `.class` files:

[image: Decompiled sources]

As for the constructor being deprecated - they deprecated it for the purpose of recreating the `Resources` when you need them for a different `Configuration`. But `Context.createConfigurationContext` doesn't let you override the source of the strings provided by resources, so I don't see any alternative.

Comment: Thanks @arekolek, your answer helped me a lot of. I didn't see the source code from Lokalise library. In the repository from github only i can download the ".aar" file.

Comment: If you include `implementation "com.lokalise.android:ota-sdk:1.3.14"` in your `build.gradle`, then you can see the decompiled code in Android Studio (see updated answer)

Comment: Interesting that you mentioned using Lokalise. I tried this and it didn't work with `androidx` lib v1.2.0 and Lokalise SDK v1.3.15, unfortunately.

Comment: @soshial We had an issue where it stopped working after upgrading `com.google.android.material:material` to `1.1.0`. We upgraded Lokalise to [2.0.0 beta](https://docs.lokalise.com/en/articles/3487109-lokalise-android-sdk-2-0-beta) and it works

Comment: @arekolek in my case it is `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0` which breaks Lokalise. Must use 1.1.0 instead. Thanks for your tip so that I can notice and take a look to `androidx.appcompat:appcompat` and `com.google.android.material:material`